# Match indentation upon newline without replacing spaces with tabs or vice versa

Tags: indentation

When I create a new line or hit `o` I have Vim configured to match the previous indentation.

However, since I use hard tabs in most places, vim will replace **any** spaces that are greater than or equal to the current shift width with hard tabs.

Since I mix tabs and spaces depending on logical indent (tabs) and alignment (spaces), this gets really annoying.

For example, take the following comment (`›` = tab, `○` = space):

```
›   /*
›   ›   Returns:
›   ›   ○○○○0 for success
›   ›   ○○○○non-zero for failure
›   */
```

If I go to the end of the `0 for success` line and hit enter (or just go to the line and, in normal mode, hit `o`), seeing as how my tab width is 4, vim will copy the indentation but replace all sequences of 4 spaces with a hard tab instead of keeping them as 4 spaces.

```
›   /*
›   ›   Returns:
›   ›   ○○○○0 for success
›   ›   ›   <-- super annoying
›   ›   ○○○○non-zero for failure
›   */
```

Here is my current indentation configuration:

```
set autoindent
set nosmartindent
set nocindent
set indentexpr=-1
set indentkeys=
filetype plugin indent off
autocmd FileType * setlocal indentkeys=
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * setlocal indentkeys=
```

---

How do I get Vim to match the indentation **exactly** when it creates a new line with automatic indentation?

Comment: did you already try `set copyindent`?

Comment: @Mass Good lord, that worked. In all of my google searches I did not come across that whatsoever. I've been dealing with this for 2 years and have looked to fix it a number of times. Can you create an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comments,

`set copyindent`

should do it